# Design of Context interface

Tags: go

My question is about a design choice for the [`Context` interface](https://golang.org/src/context/context.go?s=2437:5880#L52). If I want to create a `child` context from a `parent` I can do something like:

```
child, cancel := context.WithTimeout(parent, timeout)
```

Wouldn't it be nicer if `WithTimeout` was part of the interface, so that we could simply write:

```
child, cancel := parent.WithTimeout(timeout)
```

It seems so much cleaner to me. It is shorter, and there is no need to `import context`.

Why are the functions to produce child contexts not part of the `Context` interface?

Comment: Interesting question but — I think — off topic due to being opinion-based. Maybe the new [softwareengineering.stackexchange.com](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) would be a better fit; I don’t know.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I don't think this is a good fit for Software Engineering. Unless there happens to be a Go language developer, no one can provide the correct answer and it becomes either primarily opinion based or a request for resources that provide the answer. If it's off-topic here on Stack Overflow, I would recommend posting it to some kind of Go community or mailing list that is frequented by the development team.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the [`context.Context`](https://golang.org/pkg/context/#Context) type:

```
type Context interface {
    Deadline() (deadline time.Time, ok bool)
    Done() <-chan struct{}
    Err() error
    Value(key interface{}) interface{}
}
```

It's simple. If you were to write an implementation of it, could you do it? Yes, easily. As there are no "setter" methods, each method can just return a default / [zero value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value), and it's a "valid" implementation. That's exactly what the background and TODO contexts do ([`context.Background()`](https://golang.org/pkg/context/#Background) and [`context.TODO()`](https://golang.org/pkg/context/#TODO)).

If you would add the functions that *derive* new context from an existing one (e.g. [`context.WithCancel()`](https://golang.org/pkg/context/#WithCancel), [`context.WithDeadline()`](https://golang.org/pkg/context/#WithDeadline) etc.) as part of the `Context` interface itself, that would require to provide a (valid) implementation for all, which is not feasible; and also all of them at the same time is rarely needed, so it would be a waste of resources.

Extensions are responsible to add the implementations. If you look at how the [`context`](https://golang.org/pkg/context/) package is implemented: [`context/context.go`](https://golang.org/src/context/context.go), you'll see different `context.Context` implementations for the different "derivatives" or "extensions":

```
// An emptyCtx is never canceled, has no values, and has no deadline. It is not
// struct{}, since vars of this type must have distinct addresses.
type emptyCtx int


// A cancelCtx can be canceled. When canceled, it also cancels any children
// that implement canceler.
type cancelCtx struct {
    Context

    done chan struct{} // closed by the first cancel call.

    mu       sync.Mutex
    children map[canceler]bool // set to nil by the first cancel call
    err      error             // set to non-nil by the first cancel call
}

// A timerCtx carries a timer and a deadline. It embeds a cancelCtx to
// implement Done and Err. It implements cancel by stopping its timer then
// delegating to cancelCtx.cancel.
type timerCtx struct {
    cancelCtx
    timer *time.Timer // Under cancelCtx.mu.

    deadline time.Time
}

// A valueCtx carries a key-value pair. It implements Value for that key and
// delegates all other calls to the embedded Context.
type valueCtx struct {
    Context
    key, val interface{}
}
```

Obviously we can make up other useful extensions for `context.Context` which are not in the `context` package. If you have a new idea, would you also add that to the `Context` interface? *That would break all existing implementations*, as obviously your new idea is not implemented in others' current implementations.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO there are 2 reasons:

1. It is because `WithContext` has nothing to do with the `parent` - e.g. parent should not need and should not have any ideas about the fact you can create a child context from it. In Go ideology interface should be as minimal as possible.
2. It is more readable and clear what are you getting as output. In the current implementation `someVar, _ := context.WithTimeout(value)` is readed as `some variable is a new (:=) context with a timeout`. In your suggested version it's `someVar, _ := parent.WithTimeout(value)` it's a bit more obscure.